# after uninstalling various input ibus, ubuntu wont let me login to desktop

Tags: ubuntu, ibus

As described, i have been trying to do a clean installation of ibus-pinyin (it broke over the past couple of versions), so i went into package manager and deleted anything ibus related that i thought was installed by me.

So I restarted computer and now I can no longer login, I know the password authentication passed as there is a drum roll, but afterwards screen flashes and I am back on login.

Help

Answer (score 1):

Press `CTRL+ALT+F1` and login w/o a graphical interface to your system.
Then reinstall/delete or w/e causes the problem (check logs files).

Comment: i am getting some nonsense when i googled gave me fixes that did nothing to change the situation at all.